# multiple templates on one bootstrap modal using AngularJS

Tags: angularjs, bootstrap-modal

I've a requirement that I need to keep my modal's template changing based on some action, I don't want to close the modal and then open up a new modal every time. Is there a way that any one know how can I send a new template to that modal based on some action in that modal. I'm launching the modal template using the angularJS as shown below and I want to dynamically change the template when I'm in the modal's controller

```
$modal.open({
            templateUrl: modalOptions.template,
            controller: modalOptions.cntrlr,
            windowClass: modalOptions.winClass,
            resolve: {
                modalParams: function () {
                    return params;
                }
            }
        });
```

Answer (score 0):

Sure!

You can give your modal a specific ID and then you can use jQuery to update the HTML contained therein.

```
$('#yourmodal').html('<p>I am your new template!</p>');
```

Comment: I'm using angularJS to launch my modal. I'm launching it as shown below $modal.open({
            templateUrl: modalOptions.template,
            controller: modalOptions.cntrlr,
            windowClass: modalOptions.winClass,
            resolve: {
                modalParams: function () {
                    return params;
                }
            }
        }); How can I give Id to the modal and update the template using the angularJS

Comment: ... you did not mention Angular,  in fact you have "bootstrap" in your title and in the tag.